# Ordering view by highest group count question - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read the couple of questions about this on stack overflow but can't seem to find the answer. I am trying to display the tags in my blog by the ones with the highest count in the tags table.

Thanks to KandadaBoggu for helping me get the tags feature of the blog I am designing working. Here is the basics and my question.

Tag belongs_to :post and Post has_many :tags. The tags table is simple really, consisting of the normal scaffolded fields plus post_id and tag_name (I actually called the column 'tag_name' instead of just 'name').

in my /views/posts/index.html/erb file I correctly am displaying the tags by group and the amount of times they are being used (appearing in the tags table). I just want to know how to order them by the highest count. Here is the code, and I currently have it set to updated_at:

PostsController

```
  def index
    @tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, :order => 'updated_at DESC', :limit => 10)
    conditions, joins = {}, nil
    unless(params[:tag_name] || "").empty?
      conditions = ["tags.tag_name = ? ", params[:tag_name]]
      joins = :tags
    end
    @posts=Post.all(:joins => joins, :conditions=> conditions, :order => 'created_at DESC').paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
      format.json { render :json => @posts }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, 
   :order => 'updated_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

to this:

```
@tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, 
   :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 10)
```

Comment: That seemed to put them in alphabetical order. Not by group count.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.